# React Redux routing to different containers after login according to user type (role)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-boilerplate

I am looking for solution how to route user after login according to user type. I am using React + Redux. My router looks like:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppWrapper>
      <Helmet
        titleTemplate="Test"
        defaultTitle="Test"
      >
        <meta name="description" content="Test jwt" />
      </Helmet>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/signin" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={RegisterPage} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/foo" component={UserType1Page} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/bar" component={UserType2Page} />
        <Route path="/" component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </AppWrapper>
  );
}
```

I am using JWT token for authorization. Right now after login I just redirect user to UserTyp1Page container:

```
const response = yield call(request, requestURL, { method: 'POST', body });

if (response.accessToken) {
  // Set the user's credentials
  yield all([call(auth.setToken, response.accessToken)]);
  yield call(forwardTo, '/foo');
```

Maybe someone could show me example or guide how to accomplish goal to route according to user type?

Comment: What is the difference between these routes ?

Comment: @AlexandrMalyita, components in these routes containers are totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow certain routes based on `accessToken` and/or a specific user type or role. You need to expose these values (through `props` or `state`) so the render method can reason about them.

```
<Switch>
    {!props.accessToken &&
        <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route exact path="/signin" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={RegisterPage} />
        </React.Fragment>
    }
    {!!props.accessToken && !!props.userType1
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/foo" component={UserType1Page} />
    }
    {!!props.accessToken && !!props.userType2
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/bar" component={UserType2Page} />
    }
    <Route path="/" component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>
```

---

> But how should I forward to some component after login?

You can use the [history object](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md) to navigate after login.

`this.props.history.push('/foo');`

If `history` isn't available in your component's `props` then you can use [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) to expose it.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class MyComponent extends Component {
    afterLogin = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/foo');
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: You got me wrong. Both userType1 and userType2, need to authenticate. Jwt token contains encoded type of user. I decode it to know if it is userType1 or userType2. The question is how to route after login according to those user types. I mean that userType1, can't be router to userType2 and vice versa.

Comment: @PrEto See edits. Your actual implementation will probably be different but the basic idea is to expose the values so you can create conditional logic around them.

Comment: okay I got this part. But how should I forward to some component after login. Maybe you could offer how to change: `yield call(forwardTo, '/foo');`

Comment: @PrEto see edits. You can use the `history` object to change routes.

Answer (score 0):

Chek this way

```
 const getUserComponent = (type) => {
        const PageComponent = type;
        render <RouteComponent />;
    }
    export default function App({type}) {
        const routePath = getRoutePathByuserType(RouteComponent);
        const PageComponent = getUserComponent(type);
        // ... routes
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="routePath" component={PageComponent} />
```